# Div Stacking issue in Safari only

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm using a combination of relative /absolute positioning and z-index changes to achieve this effect in chrome:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqxFR.jpg

And it does so, but in Safari, it does this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/goNyB.jpg

Below is my CSS and HTML Markup, I'm just learning the intricacies of CSS Styling and Cross-Browser Compatability so any help would be great.

```
//Content padding for headerspace
#contact, #non-home {
  padding-top: 120px; }
  #contact .focus, #non-home .focus {
    position: relative;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
        justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center; }
    //Start of bg blur styling
    #contact .focus .blur, #non-home .focus .blur {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 2;
      min-width: 80vw;
      min-height: 600px;
      background-position: top -4px left -140px;
      background-image: url("/assets/img/italy_1.jpg");
      background-size: 119%;
      -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
              filter: blur(10px); }
   //container styling for form
   #contact .focus .container, #non-home .focus .container {
      z-index: 2;
      position: relative;
      min-width: 80vw;
      min-height: 600px;
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); }
      //direct styling on the form
      #contact .focus .container form, #non-home .focus .container form {
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column; }
        #contact .focus .container form .form-group, #non-home .focus .container form .form-group {
          width: inherit;
          padding-left: 200px;
          margin: 5px; }
          #contact .focus .container form .form-group input, #non-home .focus .container form .form-group input {
            width: 400px;
            margin-left: 50px; }
          #contact .focus .container form .form-group #name, #non-home .focus .container form .form-group #name {
            margin-left: 50px; }
          #contact .focus .container form .form-group #name-label, #non-home .focus .container form .form-group #name-label {
            margin-left: 30px; }
          #contact .focus .container form .form-group #email-label, #non-home .focus .container form .form-group #email-label {
            padding-left: 32px; }
          #contact .focus .container form .form-group #email, #non-home .focus .container form .form-group #email {
            margin-left: 50px; }
          #contact .focus .container form .form-group textarea, #non-home .focus .container form .form-group textarea {
            margin-left: 20px;
            width: 400px;
            height: 100px; }
          #contact .focus .container form .form-group #questions-label, #non-home .focus .container form .form-group #questions-label {
            position: relative;
            top: -50px;
            left: -25px;
            margin-left: -40px; }
        #contact .focus .container form .submit, #non-home .focus .container form .submit {
          margin-top: 20px;
          margin-left: 500px; }
        #contact .focus .container form p, #non-home .focus .container form p {
          margin-top: 50px;
          margin-left: 325px; }
  //formatting on the background image to place it at top right to obtain the blurred effect.
  #contact .bg, #non-home .bg {
    z-index: 1;
    min-width: 100vw;
    background-image: url("/assets/img/italy_1.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0; }
```

HTML Below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header-wrap">
        <header>
            <title>Personalized Travel Planning</title>
            <a href="/"><img class="logo" src="/assets/img/logo.jpg" /></a>
            <div class="flex-container">
                <ul class="site-nav">
                    <li><a class="about" href="/about/">About</a></li>
                    <li><a class="contact" href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a class="packages" href="/packages/">Packages</a></li>
                    <li><a class="deals" href="/deals/">Deals and Promotions</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
    <div class="content-wrap" id="contact">
        <div class="focus">
            <div class="blur"></div>
            <div class="container">
                <form method="POST" action="contact.php">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="name-label" for="name">Name:</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name (Required)" name="name" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="email-label" for="email">Email:</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="email" type="text" placeholder="someone@gmail.com (Required)" name="email" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="questions-label" for="questions">Questions/ Concerns:</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="questions" cols="40" rows="10" placeholder="Please let us know of any questions you may have!" name="questions"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="submit">
                        <input class="form-control" id="submit" type="submit" name="Submit" />
                    </div>
                    <p>Or feel free to reach out to us on Facebook! See below for a link.</p>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="bg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-wrap">
        <ul>
            <li>Personalized Travel Planning, LLC</li>
            <li>P.O. Box 54</li>
            <li>Walterboro, South Carolina 29488</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="social-wrap">
            <p>Find Us: </p>
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/PersonalizedTravelPlanning"><img class="facebook" src="/assets/img/facebook.png" /></a>
        </div>
        <p>2016. Designed by Melton Development.</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Update: Added * { box-sizing: border-box; } to the CSS and it had no effect on the layout in Safari.

SOLVED: Had to explicitly add height: 100% to the child div to get it to display correctly in Safari.

Comment: It looks like either the bady, the header-wrap div or the header element is affected by margin/padding with safari. Perhaps try expressly setting `box-sizing: border-box`for all elements to test.

Comment: @TBB So use somethin like this: `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` to test the elements?

Comment: Great! You should submit your answer and clarify which child div you meant because, without access to the code in the browser, it can be very difficult for others to understand problems like this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the height of the child div bg wasn't inherited from the parent div, container. So the height 100% attribute had to be added, and the specificity to the bg class div was wrong so that was corrected as well.

```
 //Content padding for headerspace
    #contact, #non-home {
      padding-top: 120px; }
      #contact .focus, #non-home .focus {
        position: relative;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center; }
        //Start of bg blur styling
        #contact .focus .blur, #non-home .focus .blur {
          position: absolute;
          z-index: 2;
          min-width: 80vw;
          min-height: 600px;
          background-position: top -4px left -140px;
          background-image: url("/assets/img/italy_1.jpg");
          background-size: 119%;
          -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
                  filter: blur(10px); }
       //container styling for form
       #contact .focus .container, #non-home .focus .container {
          z-index: 2;
          position: relative;
          min-width: 80vw;
          min-height: 600px;
          background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); }
          //direct styling on the form
          #contact .focus .container form, #non-home .focus .container form {
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;
            -ms-flex-direction: column;
                flex-direction: column; }
            #contact .focus .container form .form-group, #non-home .focus .container form .form-group {
              width: inherit;
              padding-left: 200px;
              margin: 5px; }
              #contact .focus .container form .form-group input, #non-home .focus .container form .form-group input {
                width: 400px;
                margin-left: 50px; }
              #contact .focus .container form .form-group #name, #non-home .focus .container form .form-group #name {
                margin-left: 50px; }
              #contact .focus .container form .form-group #name-label, #non-home .focus .container form .form-group #name-label {
                margin-left: 30px; }
              #contact .focus .container form .form-group #email-label, #non-home .focus .container form .form-group #email-label {
                padding-left: 32px; }
              #contact .focus .container form .form-group #email, #non-home .focus .container form .form-group #email {
                margin-left: 50px; }
              #contact .focus .container form .form-group textarea, #non-home .focus .container form .form-group textarea {
                margin-left: 20px;
                width: 400px;
                height: 100px; }
              #contact .focus .container form .form-group #questions-label, #non-home .focus .container form .form-group #questions-label {
                position: relative;
                top: -50px;
                left: -25px;
                margin-left: -40px; }
            #contact .focus .container form .submit, #non-home .focus .container form .submit {
              margin-top: 20px;
              margin-left: 500px; }
            #contact .focus .container form p, #non-home .focus .container form p {
              margin-top: 50px;
              margin-left: 325px; }
      //formatting on the background image to place it at top right to obtain the blurred effect.
      #contact .focus .bg, {
        z-index: 1;
        min-width: 100vw;
        **height: 100%;**
        background-image: url("/assets/img/italy_1.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0; }
```